# MySQL "many to many" relation error

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, many-to-many, constraints

I've got 3 tables in "many to many" relation.

Table A:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabA(
tabAcolA mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
tabAcolB text not null,
tabAcolC text null,
PRIMARY KEY keyA (tabAcolA)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table B:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabB(
tabBcolA mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
tabBcolB text not null,
PRIMARY KEY keyB (tabBcolA)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table C (AB joint):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabC(
    tabCcolA int unsigned not null,
    tabCcolB int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY keyC (tabCcolA,tabCcolB),
    CONSTRAINT FkeyA FOREIGN KEY (tabCcolA) 
    REFERENCES tabA(tabAcolA) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FkeyB FOREIGN KEY (tabCcolB) 
    REFERENCES tabB(tabBcolA) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

It returns an error:

```
1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: Mediumint vs int, types should match when making references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is the datatype mismatch of the columns.

The datatype of the foreign key column must be an exact match to the referenced column. e.g.

```
 fkcol  INT UNSIGNED     ref -> pkcol  INT UNSIGNED
```

or

```
 fkcol  MEDIUMINT        ref -> pkcol  MEDIUMINT
```

If we attempt to create a foreign key constraint with columns of different datatypes, InnoDB returns an error. (The behavior observed by OP.)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, after fixing this error only one index (FkeyB) appears in Indexes table. Why?

Comment: Because there is already an index suitable for use by the other foreign key.  The PRIMARY KEY (cluster index) has `tabCcolA` as a leading column. So another index with `tabCcolA` as the leading index would be redundant. (InnoDB will create an index to support a foreign key *only* if it doesn't find an existing index that is suitable.) And there is no requirement that the name of the index match the name of the foreign key.

Comment: Is it necessary to create PRIMARY KEY in join table?

Comment: We want a UNIQUE KEY if we want to prevent duplicate values... if we want to enforce a rule that a row in tabA is related to a specific row in tabB no more than one time. With NOT NULL constraints on the columns in `tabC`, a UNIQUE KEY on those two columns would be equivalent to a PRIMARY KEY, and InnoDB would use the UNIQUE KEY as the cluster key. (My personal preference would be to have a PRIMARY KEY on tabC, just as shown in the question. (But it isn't a strict requirement of InnoDB.)

Comment: Is it necessary to have a PRIMARY KEY on the join/link/association table? No, there's no strict requirement for it.  But I would choose to *not* have  a PRIMARY KEY *only* if that was solving some sort of problem. And the absence of an unnecessary index on the singleton `tabCcolA` column is not a problem. (And if that was a problem, I would add an index, not remove the PRIMARY KEY.)